# Выполнить команду в консоли для gitlab.com

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

Возник вот какой вопрос. Есть репо на gitlab.com. Хочу добавить серверный хук pre-commit. Создал папку custom_hooks, внутри добавил файл pre-commit, написал внутри просто exit 1 , чтобы проверить.
Делаю git pull, все ок, каталог подъехал, внутри файла нет (на локальном репо) - как и должно быть.
Но хук не работает, здесь пишут что нужно сделать его исполняемым

https://ealebed.github.io/posts/2017/gitlab-custom-hooks/

В связи с чем вопрос:
Каким образом выполнить эту команду

chmod +x /srv/gitlab/data/repositories/MYGROUP/MYREPO.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive

на сервере gitlab.com
Я так понимаю, можно со своего компа через bash как-то приконнектиться к серверу и отправить оттуда. Но как?

Answer (score 2):

Этого нельзя сделать, если только это не ваш внутренний GitLab, иначе это была бы уязвимость. GitLab для своих пользователей предоставляет [WebHook](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md), а также возможность проверять сообщения коммитов через регулярные выражения.

Для приватных серверов администратор может настроить серверные и системные [хуки](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html).

Comment: WebHook я потестил, но он к сожалению игнорирует ошибки возврата API HTTP. А мне нужно "заблокировать" пуш в ветку по определенным условиям (разрешить пушить определенные каталоги только определенным разработчикам)? Неужели это нельзя сделать на стороннем гитлабе?... Про два репозитория к одному проекту тоже смотрел, показалось слишком геморройным и неустойчивым, хотел блочить на хуках..

Comment: используйте `protected branch`, в них можно настроить кто в них коммитит